# Sans ou avec le pronom?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions

Je demandai à une amie la date qu'elle aimerait rencontrer le mois prochain et si elle avait une date à l'esprit. Je savais pas si je dois demander :

> Tu as une date à l'esprit que tu veux rencontrer ?

ou

> Tu as une date à l'esprit que tu veux nous rencontrer ?

*J'ai commencé à douter alors que je lui envoie un message*

Comment: As-tu une date en tête pour une rencontre? que tu veux rencontrer ne marche pas.

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe *rencontrer* ne s'utilise pas comme ça. J'aurais dit (de moins en moins formel) :

> Tu as une préférence pour la date de notre rencontre ?
>
> On doit fixer la date de notre rencontre ; tu as une préférence ?
>
> Je suis libre la semaine prochaine, on se voit mardi si ça te va !

Pour répondre à la question, c'est *se rencontrer* ou *rencontrer quelqu'un ou quelque chose*, donc il serait correct de dire :

> Tu as une date à l'esprit à laquelle tu voudrais qu'on se rencontre ?

mais je ne le tournerais pas comme ça.

Comment: Ce n'est pas "une date ... où...", mais "une date ... à laquelle...".

Comment: As-tu, non, opur une question un peu formelle ?

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax , c'est très souvent employé, et comme bien souvent, à cause de la simplicité pour des compléments de temps, mais le "où" devrait introduire un complément de lieu. L'endroit où, la maison où j'ai grandi. ...  Pour le temps, on a "auquel, pendant lequel, jusqu'au quel, tant que ..."

Answer (score 3):

Il y a plusieurs incorrections à corriger : inversion pour une phrase interrogative, pronoms pour le complément circonstanciel.

Il faudrait dire, en gardant les éléments fournis:

> As-tu une date à l'esprit à laquelle tu veux que nous nous rencontrions ?
>
> As-tu une date à l'esprit à laquelle tu veux que l'on se rencontre ?

Plus simplement:

> As-tu une date à l'esprit à laquelle se rencontrer ?
>
> As-tu une date à l'esprit pour se rencontrer ?

En langage parlé, on peut effectivement omettre l'inversion :

> Tu as une date à l'esprit pour se rencontrer ?

Comment: « Une date pour se rencontrer » ne me parait vraiment pas idiomatique.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez , une "chose" pour faire "quelque chose" est une forme passe-partout, quand "chose" est utilisé peu ou prou comme moyen: une fourchette pour manger la salade, une boutique pour acheter ..., un jeu pour "jouer", un verre pour faire la fête, une pizza pour manger, ...

Answer (score 2):

Moi, je dirais (en allant du "bien dit" au moins "bien dit" mais qu'on entend tout le temps en language parlé: 1) As-tu une date en tête pour notre rencontre?

Aussi, en language parlé: 2) T'as une date en tête pour notre rencontre? Ou encore: 3) Est-ce que tu as une date, etc. Et finalement: 4) Est-ce que t'as une date.....5) On se voit quand, alors? [très français, très colloquiale et dit souvent, à garder à l'esprit pour utilisation future]

Difficilement, je dirais: Tu as une date etc. à moins d'avoir déja entamée une conversation avec ladite amie.

Et mon point final, c'est que je ne dirais jamais dans ce contexte précis: avoir à l'esprit....une date etc.

Veuillez laisser les numéros. Aussi les crochets carrés.

Comment: +1, surtout pour "en tête".et aussi pour l'avis d'éviter "tu as" si le contexte n'est pas clair (otherwise they might think you're telling them they've got a fruit on their head/banana in their ear! [just kidding]).

Comment: Je ne pense pas que la proposition 4 soit correcte. Est ce que tu voulais dire "Est-ce _que_ t'as..." ?

Comment: Oui, je voulais écrire: Est-ce que t'as...c'est corrigé.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) [À quel moment/quand] *voudrais-tu* qu'*on se voie* ?
> (2) Il y a une date en
>   particulier *où/à laquelle*<sup>1</sup> tu voudrais qu'on se voie ?
>   (3) Y a-t-il une date qui te convienne *pour* [qu'on se/une] rencontre ?
>   (4) As-tu pensé à [une date pour/la date de] notre prochaine rencontre ?
>   (5) Quand est-ce que tu veux qu'on se rencontre / tu veux qu'on se rencontre quand ? [Québec]

Tel que le mentionne une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18294) *quand + se voir* est bien utile, et on n'est pas obligé de parler de date pour obtenir une réponse sous cette forme. En complément, dans le premier (1) exemple on a employé le conditionnel de courtoisie avec [*vouloir* + que](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vouloir/82562/difficulte), puis choisi le subjonctif avec la subordonnée (*se voir*) même si dans une langue plus près de celle qui est parlée ça pouvait avoir moins d'importance. Autrement, on peut demander de préciser comme dans le deuxième (2) exemple ; ou mettre l'accent sur le moment opportun pour l'interlocuteur comme en troisième (3) exemple. L'avant-dernier exemple (4) est davantage un rappel ou une question sur le fruit de la réflexion de notre interlocuteur suite à un échange antérieur où on lui demandait d'y réfléchir ; en employant *penser à la date de* on peut référer à une date déjà déterminée, donc à l'anticipation de la rencontre, etc. Le dernier exemple (5) est ce qui me vient à l'esprit intuitivement et j'y ai abandonné le conditionnel pour y être plus *familier* ; on pourrait y ajouter *exactement* dans le même sens que (2), c'est-à-dire à quel moment précis (*en particulier*); aussi avec *se voir*. Tous les exemples sont aussi possibles avec la deuxième personne du pluriel.

---

Pour répondre directement à la question, il faut un pronom et un tour pour l'accueillir.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On peut penser ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=date%20o%C3%B9%2Cdate%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%2C*_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%2C*_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdate%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmoment_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcas_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bd%27_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjour_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A9poque_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmesure_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpays_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btemps_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blieu_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BD%27_NOUN%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C3%A9poque_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdate_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgr%C3%A2ce_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btemp%C3%A9rature_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bquestion_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bheure_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdistance_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpersonne_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhauteur_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiscussion_NOUN%20%C3%A0%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0)) que l'emploi de [où](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/o%C3%B9) pour désigner le temps en remplacement de *à [laquelle](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/laquelle)* est moins courant ou usuel. Je ne le sais pas, mais ce ne serait pas étonnant vu que le sens temporel du pronom *où* n'est que secondaire. Par ailleurs, j'ai noté que l'entrée étymologique pour [*date*](http://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/date) au TLFi mentionne : « Empr. au lat. médiév. *data* (*littera*, *charta*), premiers mots de la formule indiquant la date où un acte a été rédigé. » (TLFi) alors qu'au *DHLH/Rey* dans une explication similaire on dit *à laquelle* dans une phrase quasi-identique. J'ai aussi trouvé dans un contexte absolument pas relié, l'*alternative séparée par barre oblique*, un exemple laissant entrevoir les deux emplois sans en traiter directement, sur [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=eng&srchtxt=date%20o%F9&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=13&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) (« La date où/à laquelle nous avons rendez-vous avec le directeur. »). Je présente donc les deux.</sub>

Comment: Toutes les phrases  sont bien dites. Le seul truc c'est qu'il y manque l'idée d'avoir quelque chose en tête. Bien évidemment, on n'est pas obligé de le dire ainsi mais la question comportait quand même l'idée d'avoir quelque chose en tête, cad, "à l'esprit", que je suppose est une traduction directe de to have in mind.....Pour le numéro 5, je ne vois pas en quoi cela serait Québecois. C'est français (toutes sortes).

Comment: La personne qui a posé la question s'est trompée en français en pensant que /avoir à l'esprit/ voulait dire: to have a date in mind, Voilà.